# Using DB2 and jdbc on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, jdbc, db2

i'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard and IBM's DB2.
I have it up and running, i already imported a schema.sql and can manipulate the database via SQL-Commands.
For connecting to the db in java i need the jdbc Driver from IBM, so i googled it and downloaded the correct version from this site: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

Then i extracted it and pasted the db2jcc.jar into my Eclipse Projects Folder.
I configured my Buildpath and now it is listed as an Referenced Library.
FYI: This is a exercise from college. So we were then adviced to copy-paste this class:
http://pastebin.com/3GYXdnxu
I did that and wrote a main method calling for openConnection. Now i am getting:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver
```

My password, as well as my username are correct.
What am I doing wrong.
Do i need to set some kind of classpath on Mac OS X?

Comment: would you post more details add some codes .....

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Rmmw4pmM This is the only code i have left to post

Answer (score 2):

On http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866, I don't see a Mac OS X-compatiable build. Windows, AIX, HPUX, Linux, Solaris are supported, but there's no build for OS X or even FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the build path (Right click on the project) and make sure the DB2 library is in the class path. Sometimes is not enough to put the jat in the project folder.

Also, if the library is present for the build, probably it is not present for the execution. You have to modify the "Run configuration" and probably modify the classpath, or the working directory.

This is not a DB2 problem, but a Java classpath problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the Universal JDBC driver (`db2jcc.jar` contains `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`), but in your code you are trying to use the old, native JDBC driver (`com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver`), which has been deprecated.  It is still available in the file `db2java.zip`, which is installed on the server in the .../sqllib/java directory.

To fix the issue, the recommended solution is to modify your code to use the universal driver class.